# Concatenating overlapping DataFrames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a rather large amount of dataframes of which each contains about 6000 to 12000 entries. They are sorted by a timestamp and some are, unfortunately, overlapping. They need to be concatenated into one very large dataframe whilst dropping duplicate timestamp entries.

I've tried merging, concatenating and appending, none of which helped very much. I have the feeling that I'm missing a crucial detail in the documentation but I can't find my error.

```
objs = [block.dataframe() for block in plot.blocks.all()]
result = pd.concat(objs, sort=True)
```

All DataFrames have the same structure

I have two specific DataFrames that overlap with the following intervals:
`objs[3] -> [20:00:00, 21:59:59]` and `objs[4] -> [20:43:27, 23:59:59]`. Upon executing the code above (which I am testing on 7 DataFrames), I receive the following error:

```
"KeyError:
['2018-12-18 15:06:20.484' '2018-12-18 15:06:21.561'\n '2018-12-18 15:06:22.638' 
...
'2018-12-18 15:59:57.553'\n '2018-12-18 15:59:58.661' '2018-12-18 15:59:59.753'] 
not in index"
```

These timestamps are from the very first DataFrame (of those 7 DataFrames). Normally, I can read errors fairly well but this one isn't really being very helpful to me.

English isn't my mothertongue so it could be a simple interpretation error that I'm having.

[Edit]

I have the following 2 csv-files (I've formatted them to something 'more understandable' since they're massive)

csv_file_4

```
0;1;2;3;4;5; ... 
0;2018-12-18 20:00:00.895;4270;558000.0;13.53336;33.599998; ...
1;2018-12-18 20:00:02.003;4270;552000.0;13.516693;34.0; ...
...
2387;2018-12-18 20:43:27.515;4270;550000.0;12.050023;31.199999; ...
...
6591;2018-12-18 21:59:58.313;4270;562000.0;12.550024;32.799999; ...
6592;2018-12-18 21:59:59.421;4270;559000.0;12.400024;32.799999; ...
```

csv_file_5

```
0;1;2;3;4;5; ...
0;2018-12-18 20:43:27.515;4270;550000.0;12.050023;31.199999; ...
1;2018-12-18 20:43:28.607;4270;553000.0;12.050023;31.199999; ...
...
10797;2018-12-18 23:59:57.917;4270;558000.0;12.116691000000001;31.199999; ...
10798;2018-12-18 23:59:59.025;4270;558000.0;12.100023;30.799999; ...
```

As described above, the first file starts with 20:00:00 and ends with 21:59:59 and the second starts with 20:43:27 and ends with 23:59:59.

As seen in the first file, the first entry from the second file is present at the 2387th line.

I'm reading those csv files with pandas which converts them to DataFrames. What I want to achieve, is to have one single DataFrame that has all the entries from both files but without the duplicates.

Editing the files and manually removing the duplicates is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: `result = pd.concat(objs, sort=True).drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: Maybe you can use `drop_duplicates` specifying the column with the timestamp? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately this error, as described above, is raised as soon as I call ```pd.concat(objs, sort=True)```. Before dropping the duplicates, I first need to concatenate them correctly.

Comment: @cmaureir I first need to successfully merge those dataframes before I can drop those duplicates.

Comment: @Albert i suggest you to please post some sample data and an expected output to replicate the issue and find a solution. :)

Comment: @anky_91 thank you for your feedback. I've added some sample data and the desired result. Currently, I'm very interested what this error implies. I don't see what it is trying to tell me. Am I calling this method wrongly?

Comment: @Albert what does `objs` look like? what is the type of its elements? please add a sample of it. I suspect that the issue lies there.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman objs are simply DataFrames in a list.

Comment: @Albert ok, but still, could you please add a sample?